# How to make a line of directories with one command?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, mkdir

With the `mkdir` command if I want this location to exist `~/test/panda/fat` when only the `~` part of it exists so far I have to do something like this:

```
mkdir ~/test
mkdir ~/test/panda
mkdir ~/test/panda/fat
```

Though it would be much more useful if I could just run something like `mkdir ~/test/panda/fat` and rather than just getting this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/$USER/test/panda/fat’: No such file or directory
```

Actually have it create the directory `test` in `~`, then the directory `panda` in `~/test`, and then finally the directory `fat` in that sub-directory. Am I missing something? Is there a way of doing this as it would be very useful? What would in fact be even more useful in certain situations is for me also to be able to also automatically create a file at the end so that it would create all those directories and then the file `bamboo.txt` in `fat` and for all this to be in the same command (obviously not requiring there to be a file at the end though).

If there is not already a command which can do this (which I would be surprised if there isn't), then how can I make a script to make this so?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" Yes. The manpage.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17674406/3701431

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-p` option of `mkdir`:

```
mkdir -p ~/test/panda/fat
```

From `man mkdir`:

```
-p, --parents
              no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

**Example:**

```
% mkdir /tmp/foo/bar
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/foo/bar’: No such file or directory

% mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar    ## Done
```

---

Now about a file creation after automatically creating the non-existing directories in between, simply put- you can't do this in one go.

At most, you can add the file generation command after the directory generation one:

```
mkdir -p ~/test/panda/fat && touch ~/test/panda/fat/bamboo.txt
```

You can use history expansion for `touch` command to make it shorter or create a shell function for convenience.

---

Here is a shell function that will do the job:

```
create_file_dir() {
    [ "$#" -ne 2 ] && echo 'Insufficient Arguments' ||

        case "$1" in -d)    mkdir -p "$2" && echo "Directory '"$2"' Created" ;;

                     -f)    mkdir -p "${2%/*}" && touch "$2" \
                              && echo "File '"$2"' Created" ;;

                      *)    echo "Invalid Argument"
        esac
}
```

Put the snippet in your `~/.bashrc`, do `source ~/.bashrc` and use it as:

```
create_file_dir -d /directories/to/create  ##For only directories
create_file_dir -f /path/to/file  ## For file with intermediate dirs
```

**Caveat:** If a file already exists, `touch` will change the timestamp.

**Example:**

```
$ create_file_dir -d /tmp/spam/egg/
Directory '/tmp/spam/egg/' Created

$ create_file_dir -f /tmp/spam/egg/foobar
File '/tmp/foo/bar/foobar' Created

$ create_file_dir /spam/egg
Insufficient Arguments

$ create_file_dir -m /spam/egg
Invalid Argument
```

Comment: And what about what I said with also making a file at the end?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda You can't do that in one operation.. You can add the file generation command after the directory generation one I.e. `mkdir -p ~/test/panda/fat && touch ~/test/panda/fat/foobar`

Comment: Well, you could probably make a simple script actually which if only `-p` is used and there is no file extension given at the end (if there is then it will give an error) does as `mkdir -p` does, however if another option is used instead, for instance, `-f` then it runs the code with `mkdir -p `with the `touch` command and the file name at the end. That shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Added..

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `-p` argument to create the parent directories as needed.

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't want to use the `-p` option, you could type:

```
mkdir  ~/test  ~/test/panda  ~/test/panda/fat
```